# zoom a Highcharts chart programmatically

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In [this JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qq4wnyqo/) I have 2 Highcharts line charts. When one of the charts is zoomed, the other chart should zoom in on the same area. The code that does this is

```
xAxis: {
    events: {
        afterSetExtremes: function (event) {
            var index = document.getElementById('container2').dataset.highchartsChart;
            var chartPartner = Highcharts.charts[index];
            chartPartner.xAxis[0].setExtremes(event.min, event.max);
            chartPartner.showResetZoom();
        }
    },
},
```

wherein `container2` is the ID of the DOM element that the other chart is rendered to. This behaviour is almost working, but there are a couple of small problems:

- After zooming-in, the gray shading area that is used to select the area to zoom doesn't disappear in Firefox (I haven't tested other browsers)
- The "Reset Zoom" button doesn't appear in the other chart despite the fact that I call `chartPartner.showResetZoom();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you called setExtremes in an infinite loop, because you told the "afterSetExtremes" event to trigger another "afterSetExtremes" event. You can prevent that easily by having a state-variable.

That's why I introduced this:

```
var updating = false;
```

and changed the last part of the events to that:

```
if (!updating) {
    updating = true;
    chartPartner.xAxis[0].setExtremes(event.min, event.max);
    chartPartner.showResetZoom();
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qq4wnyqo/1/

Edit: The original JSFiddle even produced a console error 'maximum call stack size exceeded'. Next time you probably want to look for stuff like that.

Edit: you still need to find a solution for hiding the 'reset zoom' buttons after they're used.